# Is it possible to execute some code before proceeding to the method that's mapped to the url in RESTeasy?

Tags: java, web, webserver, jax-rs, resteasy

Pretty much the title. I have to validate that client's IP address matches a list of allowed ip-s before proceeding with the requests on all methods so I was wondering if there's a way to execute some code before resteasy proceeds to executing the method mapped to url instead of copying the same logic to all the methods.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for a `ContainerRequestFilter`.

Comment: Can you give more details on this like the technology you are using?

Comment: As Turing mentioned... you can inject HttpServletRequest into the filter to get the IP

Comment: This can be done with a PreMatching `ContainerRequestFilter`. However, that will only process REST requests. If you've got servlet requests those would not be filtered. What container are you running in?